# Problem with theme in Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: themes, xubuntu

Something happened and some butttons or even whole windows looks like in Windows Classic theme.Also somethings changed in fonts.

So I realized that I had turn off Compositor in Windows Manager Tweaks. And this partly helped.It helped only in Xubuntu session, but login screen and for example ubuntu session still looks ugly..
[image: Ugly Ubuntu]

Answer (score 1):

So I realized that I had turn off Compositor in Windows Manager Tweaks. And this partly helped. It helped only in Xubuntu session, but login screen and, for example, ubuntu session still looks ugly..

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @con-f-use Actually, [it is far preferable to post an incomplete answer as an answer than as a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments). However, I agree that this answer would be benefited substantially by the addition of more information, and perhaps screenshots as well. Also, Z37, I recommend that you at least edit this to explain specifically *how* it helped (since it only "partly" did).